# Are all (non-macroscopic, non-measurement) quantum mechanical interactions time-reversible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, standard-model, arrow-of-time, time-reversal-symmetry

I distinctly remember reading some article claiming some physicists had discovered a time-irreversible, subatomic quantum mechanical interaction. Is my memory just foggy or has this really been found?

Comment: You don't need the part about "non-measurement." The Copenhagen interpretation's distinction between measurement and other physical processes is not fundamentally well defined, and the resulting wavefunction collapse is not a physical process.

Comment: What do you mean by "not a physical process?" It's something that occurs in reality, isn't it?

Comment: That word "reality" is notoriously hard to define. I would say that no, it isn't something that occurs in reality, in the sense that it's only a feature of the Copenhagen interpretation (CI), and other interpretations such as many worlds (MWI) predict all the same experimental observables without including a notion of wavefunction collapse. Another way of putting it is that the physical laws of quantum mechanics describe how quantum-mechanical systems evolve over time, and those laws do not describe any such thing as wavefunction collapse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the article was about CP violation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation ), which seems to imply violation of the symmetry with respect to time reversal.